# Need help on Databricks SQL query

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, databricks-sql

Greetings!!

I have a dataset consists of order_number,start_date,staus columns as shown below.
[image]

from the above table i need an output as single row like shown below.
[image]

in output, i need recent status and first start date.

Can anyone help me with the approach i should follow.?

Please help me. Thanks!

I tried with Dense Rank but getting either recent start date value and old status value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two separate functions for start date and status running over the same window:

```sql
SELECT distinct order_id,
                first(start_date) over (partition by order_id order by start_date
                                        rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as start_date,
                last(status) over (partition by order_id order by start_date
                                   rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as status
           FROM a_table;
```

Comment: worked like a magic.. Thank you so much Sir!